# Get return codes from previous functions

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to write a reminder script on Unix that will send me an email once certain rather time-consuming tasks are finished. I'd like it to also send me the return code of the task, but I'm struggling to get that done within the script

Right now the script looks like this:

```
AUTOMATIC_SUBJECT="$? was returned by $(history -1| cut -c 6- | head -1)"

if [[ $# = 0 ]]; then
   SUBJECT=$AUTOMATIC_SUBJECT
   BODY=""
elif [[ $# = 1 ]]; then
   SUBJECT=$AUTOMATIC_SUBJECT
   BODY=$1
elif [[ $# = 2 ]]; then
   SUBJECT=$1
   BODY=$2
fi
echo "$BODY" | mailx -s "$SUBJECT" email@address.com
```

If I run the following command:

```
cat 123;send_reminder.sh
```

Where 123 is a file that does not exist in the current directory, I get the subject "0 was returned by cat 123;send_reminder.sh" (I'll do a cut or something eventually to get rid of the ';send_reinder.sh', but that's not important right now).

However, if I run

```
cat 123;send_reminder.sh "cat 123 returned $?" "body"
```

I get "cat 123 returned 2" as the subject. Note the position of the "$?", in the script I need it before I do the history command or else it will return that error code.

So the question is, why isn't my script returning the right error code? I have a feeling it has something to do with assigning it to the automatic_subject variable, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Comment: Actually when you rum cat 123;send_reminder.sh that means your recent command run is send_reminder.sh so $? will be returned 0 if this script run positive at the end of line.so most probably $subject is empty in this case

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, how could $? provide the return code of the script I'm currently running?

Comment: To get the `$?` value right, try: `cat 123; source send_reminder.sh` or, with less typing, `cat 123; . send_reminder.sh`.  (This has the mild side-effect that shell variables AUTOMATIC_SUBJECT, SUBJECT and BODY will be left in the current environment.)  Alternatively, you will need to pass `$?` in on the command line.

Comment: sorry i interpreted wrong..

Comment: That worked! That side effect is easily avoided by setting TEMP_BODY=$BODY at the beginning of the script and then BODY=$TEMP_BODY at the end. Now I might run into a problem with getting the right history variable if I'm running other commands in the meantime but that's a separate problem. Care to turn your comment into an answer John? I promise to accept/upvote it

Comment: @Nickolai Glad it worked.  Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `$?` value right, try:

```
cat 123; source send_reminder.sh
```

or, equivalently, but with less typing:

```
cat 123; . send_reminder.sh.
```

Sourcing the script means that it is executed in the current shell.  This has the mild side-effect that shell variables, such as AUTOMATIC_SUBJECT, SUBJECT and BODY, will be left in the current environment.

Alternatively, you will need to pass `$?` in on the command line.